# List.ForEach in vb.net - perplexing me

Tags: vb.net, foreach, generic-list

Consider the following code example:

```
    TempList.ForEach(Function(obj)
        obj.Deleted = True
    End Function)
```

And this one:

```
    TempList.ForEach(Function(obj) obj.Deleted = True)
```

I would expect the results to be the same, however the second code example does NOT change the objects in the list TempList.

This post is more to understand why...? Or at least get some help understanding why...

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It's because you used `Function` instead of `Sub`. Since a `Function` returns a value, the compiler considers that the equals sign (=) is used as a comparison, not an assignment. If you change `Function` to `Sub`, the compiler would correctly consider the equals sign as an assignment:

```
TempList.ForEach(Sub(obj) obj.Deleted = True)
```

If you had a multiline lambda; you wouldn't have had this problem:

```
TempList.ForEach(Function(obj)
                     obj.Deleted = True
                     Return True
                 End Function)
```

Obviously, for the ForEach method it makes no sense to use a `Function` because the return value wouldn't be used, so you should use a `Sub`.

Comment: Ahhh that makes perfect sense now, many thanks for that. It's all still quite new to me :-)

Comment: I must admit that at first, I didn't know what was going on either ;-)

Comment: I'm amazed at how powerful this stuff is, forcing myself to learn this as well is LINQ.